# Yuasa as battery replacement for APC Battery

Tags: battery, ups

I am not familiar with UPS battery but we have a SMT SmartUPS 1500 with battery that needs replacement. We went into a vendor asking for the RCB7 but instead provided with a Yuasa VRLA Battery 12V 17AH (Model : NP17-12).

May I know whether the product is a good replacement for the UPS battery?

Answer (score 0):

It is a good replacement.  I have used it on 3 different HP UPSs, with no issues whatsoever.

Comment: Hi. Thank you for the information. How about the connector? APC has this connector but Yuasa doesn't have any (judging by the pictures). How do you connect it? Thanks for the enlightenment.